# GCDAsyncSocket peer to peer connection

Tags: ios, macos, wifi, asyncsocket

I'm trying to use GCDAsyncSocket to establish a peer to peer connection between my Mac and my iPhone. Currently both devices are connected under the same wifi. But using the method:

```
[asyncSocket connectToHost:@"my iPhone's IP address" onPort:80 error:&err]
```

does not work. Is it due to my false operation? Could you please explain how to set up a peer to peer connection under my circumstance?

Comment: Is the iPhone listening on port 80?

Answer (score 0):

I've found out a way to do that. If you're using GCDAsyncSocket, there's a demo called BonjourServer & BonjourClient. In its code, there's a delegate method:

```
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didAcceptNewSocket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)newSocket
{   

DDLogInfo(@"Accepted new socket from %@:%hu", [newSocket connectedHost], [newSocket connectedPort]);

// The newSocket automatically inherits its delegate & delegateQueue from its parent.

[connectedSockets addObject:newSocket];

connectedSocket = newSocket;
}
```

When you set up a peer to peer connection between the server and client, you can send data in the method specified above.